# Creating a for loop to double the previous value

Tags: java, for-loop, parameters, expression, bluej

I am currently in the process of learning Java and I have an assignment that asks me to write a for loop. I need to create a small program that allows user input then uses the for loop to put a message telling the user their info. I need the for loop to allow, to sum up the number of days the user put and for each day they grain and I also need to get double the amount of grain for each day.

EXAMPLE:

Day 1 you get 1 grain of rice for a total of 1 grain

Day 2 you get 2 grains of rice for a total of 3 grains

Day 3 you get 4 grains of rice for a total of 7 grains

Day 4 you get 8 grains of rice for a total of 15 grains

Day X you get X grains of rice for a total of Y grains

I am not totally sure how to set up my for loop to do this. Here is what I have so far.

```
    public static void GrainCounter()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many days worth of grain do you have?");
    int days = s.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++)
    {
     sum = sum + i;
    }
    System.out.print("Day " + days + " you got " + sum + " grains of rice");
}
```

Comment: Please follow a simple Java tutorial, it will point it out clearly, plus a bunch of other *useful* stuff.

Comment: Please add ypur code here instead of an image.

Comment: `sum += 1 << i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is actually,

> ```
> Day X you get 2**X grains of rice for a total of Y grains
> ```

Your `sum` should start at `1`, and you should put your `print` **in** the loop (also you want to print `i` for the day). Something like,

```
System.out.println("Day 1 you get 1 grain of rice for a total of 1 grain");
int sum = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
{
 sum += Math.pow(2, i);
 System.out.println("Day " + (i + 1) + " you got " + (int)Math.pow(2,i) + 
     " grains of rice for a total of " + sum + " grains");
}
```

You could also write the `println` as

```
System.out.printf("Day %d you got %d grains of rice for a total of %d grains%n",
        i + 1, (int) Math.pow(2, i), sum);
```

Comment: I don't know why accepted your answer even it gives wrong result!!! Have you run it?!

Comment: @John I did have a bug in the `sum` line location (which I've fixed), why did you accept my answer?

Comment: It's not me who asked the question :)

Comment: @John Oops. Sorry. :)

Comment: No worries Elliott  :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is initialize `rice` with `1` and just keep adding it to itself in a `for`-loop until your loop iterator `int i` reaches the number of days - 1 (because you initialize with 1, so no extra iteration)

```
public static int doubleDays(int days) {
        int rice = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < days - 1; i++) {
            rice += rice;
        }
        return rice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GrainCounter{
  public static void main(String[] agrs){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How Many Days Worth Of Grain Do You Have?");
      int days = in.nextInt();
      int sum =1, dailySum=1;
      System.out.println("Day 1 you get 1 grain of rice for a total of 1 grain");
      for (int i =1; i <days; i++){
          dailySum*=2;
          sum +=dailySum;
          System.out.print("Day "+  (i+1) +  " you get "  + dailySum   
                                                + " grain of rice for a total of " 
                                                +  sum + " grain\n");  
     }
  }
}
```

the result would be for 10 days :

```
How Many Days Worth Of Grain Do You Have?
10
Day 1 you get 1 grain of rice for a total of 1 grain
Day 2 you get 2 grain of rice for a total of 3 grain
Day 3 you get 4 grain of rice for a total of 7 grain
Day 4 you get 8 grain of rice for a total of 15 grain
Day 5 you get 16 grain of rice for a total of 31 grain
Day 6 you get 32 grain of rice for a total of 63 grain
Day 7 you get 64 grain of rice for a total of 127 grain
Day 8 you get 128 grain of rice for a total of 255 grain
Day 9 you get 256 grain of rice for a total of 511 grain
Day 10 you get 512 grain of rice for a total of 1023 grain
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your code tries to use the day as the variable, but in fact your variable is actually the previous days gain.

```
public static void GrainCounter(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many days worth of grain do you have?");
    int days = s.nextInt();
    int sum = 1;
    previousDay = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= days; i++){
        sum += previousDay*2;
        previousDay = previousDay*2;
    }
    System.out.print("Day " + days + " you got " + sum + " grains of rice");
}
```